# Building runConfiguration xml for Maven for group of tests that are Taged with annotation @Tag("regression)

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin, run-configuration

Maven can't find test that are tag with annotation @Tag("regression)

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test (default-test) on project fees-module: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]`

So currently my project structure for tests looks like thes:
src/test
src/integration-test

in pom there is declaration of every test direcotry in 
Surefire plugin have also  and exldude so tests from src/test and src/integration-test can be build after each.

Currently xml looks like this :

```
 <MavenRunnerParameters>
          <option name="profiles">
            <set />
          </option>
          <option name="goals">
            <list>
              <option value="clean" />
              <option value="install" />
              <option value="failsafe:integration-test" />
              <option value="-Dgroups=regression" />
            </list>
          </option>
          <option name="pomFileName" />
          <option name="profilesMap">
            <map />
          </option>
          <option name="resolveToWorkspace" value="false" />
          <option name="workingDirPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        </MavenRunnerParameters>
```

and it works only when i Tag test from src/test
when a test is taged from src/integration-test failure pops out